# Screen variable by given conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to use dplyr::filter to screen variable under the specific condition. It's no problem to get the filtering result by using the following method:

```
    mtcars %>% filter(cyl == 4)
```

or

```
    var <- 4
    mtcars %>% filter(cyl == var)
```

However, I can't generate the same result if I defined the given condition outside the filter function if I use the same name as a variable. For example:

```
    cyl <- 4
    mtcars %>% filter(cyl %in% cyl) # not work
    mtcars %>% filter(cyl == cyl) # not work
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ANSWER**
If you really want to then:

```
cyl<-4
mtcars %>% 
  filter(cyl==(!!cyl))
```

**Notes on Good Practice** 
You need to use a different variable name. Otherwise, this is what you're doing:R looks for cyl in the dataset first.

```
mtcars %>% 
  filter(cyl==cyl)
```

This changes nothing.
However, as you've noted;this works:

```
    mycyl<-4
   mtcars %>% 
      filter(cyl==mycyl)
```